# Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?

```
var o = {
  '1': 1,
  'a': 2,
  'b': 3
}

Object.keys(o); // ["1", "a", "b"] - is this ordering guaranteed by ES6?

for(let k in o) {
  console.log(k);
} // 1 2 3 - is this ordering guaranteed by ES6?
```

Comment: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nailing-object-property-order

Comment: Btw, for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` and `Reflect.ownKeys` the order *is* defined.

Comment: Actually - the answer is again - no longer up to date :) ES2016 introduced iteration order for `Object.keys` and `for.. in` loops and the spec: 19.1.2.16 (Object.keys) calls 7.3.21 (EnumerateOwnProperties) which in turn guarantees: "Order the elements of properties so they are in the same relative order as would be produced by the Iterator that would be returned if the EnumerateObjectProperties internal method were invoked with O." - EnumerateOwnProperties in turn guarantees `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` (9.1.11) which does 9.1.11.1 (ordinaryownpropertykeys) which guarantees order.

Comment: The numbers are from the ES2017 spec (8) which can be found freely here: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't see where [13.7.5.15 *EnumerateObjectProperties*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) guarantees the same order as *[[OwnPropertyKeys]]*. It only says "*…must obtain the own property keys […] by calling [the] internal method*". What is does with them after obtaining, or how they are merged with the inherited properties, is left to the implementation.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Note:** As of ES2020, even older operations like `for-in` and `Object.keys` are required to follow property order. That doesn't change the fact that using property order for fundamental program logic probably isn't a good idea, since the order for non-integer-index properties depends on when the properties were created.

---

Answer for ES2015-ES2019:

For `for-in`, `Object.keys`, and `JSON.stringify`: **No.**

For some other operations: **Yes**, usually.

While ES6 / ES2015 adds property order, it does not require `for-in`, `Object.keys`, or `JSON.stringify` to follow that order, due to legacy compatibility concerns.

[`for-in`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) loops iterate according to [[[Enumerate]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate), which is defined as (emphasis mine):

> When the [[Enumerate]] internal method of *O* is called the following
> steps are taken:
>
> Return an Iterator object ([25.1.1.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iterator-interface)) whose next method iterates
> over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of *O*. The
> Iterator object must inherit from %IteratorPrototype% ([25.1.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25iteratorprototype%25-object)).
> The mechanics and **order** of enumerating the properties **is not
> specified** but must conform to the rules specified below <sup>[1]</sup>.

ES7 / ES2016 removes the [[Enumerate]] internal method and instead uses the abstract operation [EnumerateObjectProperties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-enumerate-object-properties), but just like [[Enumerate]] it doesn't specify any order.

And also see this quote from [`Object.keys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys):

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the
> for-in statement, [...]

That means **implementations are NOT required to define a specific order of enumeration**. This [has been confirmed](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/property-ordering-of-enumerate-getownpropertynames) by Allen Wirfs-Brock, Project Editor of the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification, in a post made after the specification was complete.

Other operations, like [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames), [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols), [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), and [`Reflect.ownKeys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) do follow the following order for ordinary objects:

1. Integer indices (if applicable), in ascending order.
2. Other string keys (if applicable), in property creation order.
3. Symbol keys (if applicable), in property creation order.

This behavior is defined in the [[[OwnPropertyKeys]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) internal method. But certain [exotic objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exotic-object) define that internal method slightly differently. For example, a Proxy's `ownKeys` trap may return an array in any order:

```js
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys: () => ['3','1','2']
}))); // ['3','1','2'], the integer indices are not sorted!
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Below it says:

> [[Enumerate]] must obtain the own property keys of the target object
> **as if** by calling its [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method.

And the order of [[OwnPropertyKeys]] is well-defined. But don't let that confuse you: that "as if" only means "the same properties", not "the same order".

This can be seen in [EnumerableOwnNames](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enumerableownnames), which uses [[OwnPropertyKeys]] to get the properties, and then it orders them

> in the same relative order as would be produced by the Iterator that
> would be returned if the [[Enumerate]] internal method was invoked

If [[Enumerate]] were required to iterate with the same order as [[OwnPropertyKeys]], there wouldn't be any need to reorder.

Comment: I actually can't find info how getOwnPropertyNames does guarentee the order? And in reality Firefox and Chrome return with this `Object.getOwnPropertyNames({ 20 : 'a', 10 : 'b' })` the `[ "10", "20" ]` numeric ordering and not the written order.

Comment: @Ciantic The order of [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames) is specified in [\[\[OwnPropertyKeys\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), and yes, it's not only by creation order.

Comment: Please see my comment above on the question - this changed since 2015 @Oriol

Comment: Just curious how an order requirement for `for-in` or `Object.keys` would be a *legacy compatibility concerns*?

Comment: Worth noting that while the spec doesn't require `for-in` or `Object.keys` to follow the order, current versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Edge all do: http://jsfiddle.net/arhbn3k2/1/ Which makes sense, it would be odd to have more than one enumeration implementation. The spec didn't require it because different engines already had behavior-in-the-wild that was different from the newly-defined order and the committee didn't want to require implementations to potentially break existing code. The implementations appear to have decided to, though; Firefox's order certainly used to be different.

Comment: @user10089632 Haha! Great question... the answer *might* be that old code that *should* be broken would work OK... at least in that respect! This could lead, I suppose, to Exceptions not being thrown when they should be, and completely alter behaviour. I doubt whether updated specs are, or could ever be, as scrupulous as that in all cases however.

Comment: @Oriol I think this answer could be improved by adding a clarification at the very top, with words to the effect that objects in JavaScript should not be semantically treated as ordered.

Comment: @52d6c6af - It is correct in that **ES2015**, specifically, didn't require `Object.keys` and such to follow the new order. It isn't correct in that ES2020 **does** now require it, not least because engines had updated (see my comment above from 2017) to do so. Since Oriol no longer contributes to SO, I've added a note to the top of the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is a good thread and answer overall. However there is one question remaining, from my view point : how is  insertion order / order of properties influenced by extensions / deprecations that vendors may ship? For example, if a vendor was to redefine the HTMLElement API or add methods to it.  Would the insertion order of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLElement.prototype OR HTMLElement.prototype)` be retained? Or, would these new additions / deprecations result in new ordering? This is critical for longevity of golfing via alias.

Comment: @Pythonista - I'm afraid I have no idea what "golfing via alias" means, and I don't see the significance of listing `HTMLElement.prototype` twice like that with `OR` in-between. But I think I can answer the overall question: As far as I'm aware, there's no guarantee what the order of properties is in host-provided objects, it could vary vendor to vendor, or release to release. In general, you have no guarantee of the order of properties in objects you don't assemble yourself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Code golfing using aliases = mapping  to 1-char equivalents via aliasing the APIs. For example, Han characters (3-bytes I believe?) above 45k+ in terms of char codes tends to be fairly unique with large gaps for "padding" should there be inheritance such as EventTarget->Node->HTMLElement->derivatives wherein your aliasing would otherwise be non-unique from iterative char maps. The utility of which is context dependent hence the `OR` depending on Object, prototype, or `__proto__`.  And longevity is dependent on insertion order. Regardless, thanks for clarifying - what I expected.

Answer (score 15):

As covered in the other answer, ES2015 does not define enumeration order for the (very commonly used) property iteration methods `for-in`, `Object.keys`, and `JSON.stringify`, whereas it *does* define enumeration methods for other methods like `Reflect.ownKeys`. **However, this inconsistency will soon no longer exist, and *all* property iteration methods will iterate in a predictable manner.**

As many have probably observed in their own experience with JS and in the comments, although property iteration order is not guaranteed by the specification for those methods above, every implementation almost always iterates in the same deterministic order anyway. As a result, there is a (finished) proposal to change the specification to make this behavior official:

[Specifying for-in enumeration order](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-for-in-order) ([Stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md))

With this proposal, under most circumstances, `for..in`, `Object.keys` / `values` / `entries`, and `JSON.stringify` are guaranteed to iterate in order over:

(1) Numeric array keys

(2) non-Symbol keys, in insertion order

(3) Symbol keys, in insertion order

Which is the same order as with `Reflect.ownKeys` and the other methods which are already guaranteed to iterate this way.

The [specification text](http://tc39.es/proposal-for-in-order/) is rather simple: `EnumerateObjectProperties`, the problematic abstract method invoked by `for..in`, etc, whose order *used* to be unspecified, [will now](http://tc39.es/proposal-for-in-order/#sec-%foriniteratorprototype%.next) call [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys), which is the internal method for which iteration order *is* specified.

There are a few weird cases which implementations currently do *not* agree on, and in such cases, the resulting order will [continue be unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013/), but such cases are few and far between.

Answer (score 11):

This question is about EcmaScript 2015 (ES6). But it should be noted that the EcmaScript2017 specification has [removed](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object.keys) the following paragraph that previously appeared in the specification for `Object.keys`, here quoted from [the EcmaScript 2016 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object.keys):

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the for-in statement, the same order must be used for the elements of the array returned in step 3.

Furthermore, the EcmaScript 2020 specification [removes](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-enumerableownpropertynames) the following paragraph from the section on `EnumerableOwnPropertyNames`, which still appears [in the EcmaScript 2019 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-enumerableownpropertynames):

> 5. Order the elements of *properties* so they are in the same relative order as would be produced by the Iterator that would be returned if the EnumerateObjectProperties internal method were invoked with *O*.

These removals mean that from EcmaScript 2020 onwards, `Object.keys` enforces the same specific order as `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Reflect.ownKeys`, namely the one specified in [OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys). The order is:

1. Own properties that are *array indexes*,<sup>1</sup> in ascending numeric index order
2. Other own String properties, in ascending chronological order of property creation
3. Own Symbol properties, in ascending chronological order of property creation

<sup>1</sup> An [array index](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#integer-index) is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String<sup>2</sup> whose numeric value *i* is an integer in the range +0 ≤ *i* < 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

<sup>2</sup> A [canonical numeric String](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-canonicalnumericindexstring) is a String representation of a Number that would be produced by `ToString`, or the string "-0". So for instance, "012" is *not* a canonical numeric String, but "12" is.

It should be noted that all major implementations had already aligned with this order years ago.

Comment: Raises the question as to what order properties get when they are inserted with the same operation. E.g. object literals or `Object.assign()`. It might be lexical or coming from the input object in the latter case, but does it have to?

Comment: @RobertSiemer - That's well-defined in the spec: Properties in an object literal are added in source code order (that's been true forever), and the behavior of `Object.assign` (and property spread) follows the property order of the source object(s). So `Object.keys({a:1,b:2})` is (now) reliably `["a","b"]` and `Object.keys({b:2,a:1})` is (now) reliably `["b","a"]`. But in general, best not to rely on object property iteration order. Relying on the order of creation/assignment is fine (and common: `const copy = {...original, x: true};` reliably creates results in `copy.x` being `true`). :-)